# Filtering MSMQ Count?

Tags: powershell, count, filtering, msmq

I'm trying to filter the count for incoming queues and I have it printing all of the queues and the count, but I want to specifically show just the queues containing the word "dev". How would I go about this?

```
gwmi -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue -computerName $myServer |
ft -property Name,MessageInQueue
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could use the `where-object` filter? Insert in your command `Where-Object{ $_.Name -like "*dev*"}` just after `$myServer |`. Not sure if the Name property contains the data which you need to filter on but you should get the idea.

Comment: That worked well, think I was putting it in the wrong place in the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where-Object is what you are describing.

Insert in your command

```
Where-Object{ $_.Name -like "*dev*"}
```

just after `$myServer |`.